# Unable to get Azure Consumption Detail

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell, azure-cli

I am using the below command to fetch the Azure Consumption  Detail. However, this seems to be not working now. Can someone tell me, if I missing out on anything?

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-AzBillingPeriod -MaxCount 3
WARNING: Upcoming breaking changes in the cmdlet 'Get-AzBillingPeriod' :
The cmdlet is being deprecated. There will be no replacement for it.
Note : Go to https://aka.ms/azps-changewarnings for steps to suppress this breaking change warning, and other
information on breaking changes in Azure PowerShell.


Name                   : 202203-1
BillingPeriodStartDate : 2022-01-02
BillingPeriodEndDate   : 2022-02-01

Name                   : 202202-1
BillingPeriodStartDate : 2021-12-02
BillingPeriodEndDate   : 2022-01-01

PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-AzConsumptionUsageDetail -BillingPeriodName 202202-1
Get-AzConsumptionUsageDetail : Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest'
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-AzConsumptionUsageDetail -BillingPeriodName 202202-1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzConsumptionUsageDetail], ErrorResponseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Consumption.Cmdlets.UsageDetails.GetAzureRmConsumptionUsageDetail
```

**Resolution:**

If I specify Start & End Date then I get the results correctly. So I feel, if the billing date is not getting started from 1st of Every Month then also we get the above error I guess. In that case, we need to find the Start and End Date to get the results.

```
 Get-AzConsumptionUsageDetail -StartDate 2021-12-02 -EndDate 2022-01-01
```

Comment: hello @Gokulnath Kumar , Can you please tell me what permissions you have on subscription level and tenant level and what is the subscription type i.e. offer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently , the ***Powershell API*** to ***get subscription consumption details only supports Enterprise Subscriptions***. There is also a [Github Issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/12561) for the same.

**I tried the same operation on 2 of my subscriptions :**

[image]

[image]

***If You run command with debug then you can also see why it is giving bad request :***

```
 Get-AzConsumptionUsageDetail -BillingPeriodName 202202-1 -debug
```

[image]

**Update :**

As **Gokulnath Kumar** mentioned , In `Pay-as-you-go` subscription it seems to work if provide `start date` and `end date` with the command as per your **Billing Period Start Date** and **Billing Period End Date** like below :

```
Get-AzConsumptionUsageDetail -StartDate 2021-11-27 -EndDate 2021-12-26
```

Comment: How to check whether I am using Enterprise or Non Enterprise Subscription.

Comment: Can you tell the offer type or offer Id of the subscription that you are using or else if you do use a debug command you can see if the subscription is supported or not as shown in the image I have posted .

Comment: Offer Name: Pay-As-You-Go and Offer ID: MS-AZR-0003P

Comment: @GokulnathKumar, So its a personal Pay-As-You-Go subscription , If its an enterprise subscription then an enterprise will make an agreement with microsoft and then will get some subscription which will then be given to the members in the organization . same as Visual Studio Enterprise Subscription. You can refer this for more details on the sub types in azure : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/offer-details/

Comment: It seems to work when I provide the correct Start and End Date of my Billing Cycle. So if possible, kindly update the answer with that suggestions too.. Anyways, I have accepted this answer.

Comment: hello @GokulnathKumar, In my subscription I am not able to do it using correct start date and end date as well  .. If you want, can you please add the screenshot in my answer by editing , it will be very helpful