# How can i view cost per resource per Location in Azure?

Tags: azure, powershell

I have gone to Azure Cost Management and viewed by Location. But I want to view the resources by location and view the cost of each resource .
How can i get this from Azure or Powershell ?

I have tried to filter from the cost management screen , but can only get the filter by location and not resource .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried to make a cost list based on location as per the Location in Azure and I was able to provision the requirement successfully.

To view the cost of each resource by location in Azure Cost Management, you can use Azure PowerShell. Here's how you can achieve this

```
  Install-Module -Name Az
  Connect-AzAccount
```

Once you are connected, you can use the  Get-AzConsumptionUsageDetail  cmdlet to retrieve the cost details for each resource by location. Here's an example command:

```
$usageDetails = Get-AzConsumptionUsageDetail | Where-Object { $_.PretaxCost -ne $null }

$groupedDetails = $usageDetails | Group-Object InstanceLocation | ForEach-Object {
    $location = $_.Name
    $locationDetails = $_.Group | ForEach-Object {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Location         = $_.InstanceLocation
            ResourceName     = $_.InstanceName
            PretaxCost       = $_.PretaxCost
        }
    }
    $totalCost = ($locationDetails | Measure-Object PretaxCost -Sum).Sum
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Location = $location
        TotalPretaxCost = $totalCost
        ResourceDetails = $locationDetails
    }
}

# Format the output as a table
$groupedDetails | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hi , thanks for the reply . Each region would have a number of resources, how can i get the cost of each resource in each location ?

Comment: Also the above gives an error  Get-AzConsumptionUsageDetail : Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest' ?

Comment: Hi, @Traci I have updated the Powershell code as you requested and provisioned the required output you're looking for. The error you're getting is because the account you're using is non enterprise account subscription. For more information on this please follow the [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70655921/unable-to-get-azure-consumption-detail)

Comment: i have tried your Link, cant seem to get past that error. I even tried with start and end dates , still no luck , any ideas, does it work for you with a non enterprise account  ?

Comment: You didn't provide any info in the query mentioning that you are using a non-enterprise account. However, I tried using both accounts and by going through the link mentioned I understood that a non-enterprise doesn't have the privilege to access the info you are looking for.

Comment: So in other words there is no way i can get the info if it is a non enterprise account ? I thought that if you provide start and end date with Get-AzConsumptionUsageDetail it will give back some info ? Also can i use "az consumption detail list" on a non enterprise account ?

Comment: Get-AzConsumptionUsageDetail -BillingPeriodName "name-of-bill-period" -debug

Use this command and check the type of your account whether it is an enterprise or non enterprise account subscription. If it falls under non-enterprise you don't have the privilege to access it. If it's an enterprise subscription then an enterprise will agree with Microsoft and then will get some subscription which will then be given to the members of the organization.
ref: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/offer-details/

Comment: It errors:    "Subscription scope usage is not supported for current api version. Please use api version after 2019-10-01

Comment: Your account doesn't have enough permissions as it was a non-enterprise account. Please try checking with the account that has enough permissions(i.e., Enterprise account).

Comment: Its strange because i can see the invoices in the Azure portal , so i thought that would be enough permission. I thought i could see it in the portal via some filters. But I have tried filtering couldnt see where it would show you cost per resource per location. Would you know ?

Comment: If you have an enterprise account You have the privilege to access the info. To access the info using the portal follow the steps mentioned

**Azure portal Login -- > Cost Management + Billing -->  Cost analysis --> In the "Group by" section, select "Location". --> Cost by resource**